# Code Golf Christmas Edition: How to print out a Christmas tree of height N

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

Given a number `N`, how can I print out a Christmas tree of height `N` using the least number of code characters?  `N` is assumed constrained to a minimum value of `3`, and a maximum value of `30` (bounds and error checking are not necessary). `N` is given as the one and only command line argument to your program or script.

All languages appreciated, if you see a language already implemented and you can make it shorter, edit if possible - comment otherwise and hope someone cleans up the mess.  Include newlines and White Spaces for clarity, but don't include them in the character count.

A Christmas tree is generated as such, with its "trunk" consisting of only a centered "*"

N = 3:

```
   *
  ***
 *****
   *
```

N = 4:

```
    *
   ***
  *****
 *******
    *
```

N = 5:

```
     *
    ***
   *****
  *******
 *********
     *
```

N defines the height of the branches not including the one line trunk.

**Merry Christmas PPCG!**

Answer (score 49, accepted):

## [J](http://www.jsoftware.com/), 24 characters

`(,{.)(}:@|."1,.])[\'*'$~`

```
   (,{.)(}:@|."1,.])[\'*'$~5
    *    
   ***   
  *****  
 ******* 
*********
    *
```

Explanation:

```
'*'$~5
*****

[\'*'$~5
*    
**   
***  
**** 
*****
```

Then `}:@|."1` reverses each row and strips off the last column, and `,.` staples it to `]`.

Then `,{.` pastes the first column onto the bottom.

*Previous entries*:

29 characters, no spaces at all.

```
   ((\:i.@#),}.)"1$&'*'"0>:0,~i.3
  *
 ***
*****
  *
   ((\:i.@#),}.)"1$&'*'"0>:0,~i.11
          *
         ***
        *****
       *******
      *********
     ***********
    *************
   ***************
  *****************
 *******************
*********************
          *
```

---

```
   NB. count from 1 to n, then 1 again
   >:0,~i.3
1 2 3 1
   NB. replicate '*' x times each
   $&'*'"0>:0,~i.3
*
**
***
*
   NB. reverse each row
   (\:i.@#)"1$&'*'"0>:0,~i.3
  *
 **
***
  *
   NB. strip off leading column
   }."1$&'*'"0>:0,~i.3

*
**

   NB. paste together
   ((\:i.@#),}.)"1$&'*'"0>:0,~i.3
  *
 ***
*****
  *
```

Comment: With just 9 more characters you can give this function a name: `c=:[:((\:i.@#),}.)"1[:$&'*'"0[:>:0,~i.`

Comment: What, do you guys use some sort of J documentation library to understandable-ize the code? :)

Answer (score 110):

## Brainfuck, 240 characters

```
              ,
             >++
            +++++
           +[-<---
          --->],[>+
         +++++++[-<-
        ----->]<<[->+
       +++++++++<]>>]<
      [->+>+>>>>>>>+<<<
     <<<<<<]>>>>++++++++
    [-<++++>]>++++++[-<++
   +++++>]+>>>++[-<+++++>]
  <<<<<<[-[>.<-]<[-<+>>+<]<
 [->+<]>>>>>[-<.>>+<]>[-<+>]
>.<<++<<<-<->]>>>>>>>-[-<<<<<
           <.>>>
           >>>]<
           <<<<.
```

<strike>Not yet done.  It works, but only with single-digit numbers.</strike>

EDIT: Done!  Works for interpreters using 0 as EOF.  See `NOTE`s in commented source for those with -1.

EDIT again: I should note that because Brainfuck lacks a standard method for reading command line arguments, I used stdin (standard input) instead.  ASCII, of course.

EDIT a third time: Oh dear, it seems I stripped `.` (output) characters when condensing the code.  Fixed...

Here's the basic memory management of the main loop.  I'm sure it can be heavily optimized to reduce the character count by 30 or so.

1. Temporary
2. Copy of counter
3. Counter (counts to 0)
4. Space character (decimal 32)
5. Asterisk character (decimal 42)
6. Number of asterisks on current line (1 + 2*counter)
7. Temporary
8. New line character
9. Temporary?
10. Total number of lines (i.e. input value; stored until the very end, when printing the trunk)

Condensed version:

```
,>++++++++[-<------>],[>++++++++[-<------>]<<[->++++++++++<]>>]<[->+>+>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]>>>>++++++++[-<++++>]>++++++[-<+++++++>]+>>>++[-<+++++>]<<<<<<[-[>.<-]<[-<+>>+<]<[->+<]>>>>>[-<.>>+<]>[-<+>]>.<<++<<<-<->]>>>>>>>-[-<<<<<<.>>>>>>]<<<<<.
```

And the pretty version:

```
ASCII to number
,>
++++++++[-<------>]  = 48 ('0')

Second digit (may be NULL)
,
NOTE:   Add plus sign here if your interpreter uses negative one for EOF
[ NOTE: Then add minus sign here
 >++++++++[-<------>]
 <<[->++++++++++<]>>  Add first digit by tens
]

Duplicate number
<[->+>+>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<]>>

Space char
>>++++++++[-<++++>]

Asterisk char
>++++++[-<+++++++>]

Star count
+

New line char
>>>++[-<+++++>]<<<

<<<

Main loop
[
Print leading spaces
-[>.<-]

Undo delete
<[-<+>>+<]
<[->+<]
>>

Print stars
>>>[-<.>>+<]

Add stars and print new line
>[-<+>]
>.<
<++

<<<

-<->
End main loop
]

Print the trunk
>>>>>>>
-[-<<<<<<.>>>>>>]
<<<<<.

Merry Christmas =)
```

Comment: my brain feels f.....sick

Comment: Oh my      god.

Comment: I found [this version online](http://www.hevanet.com/cristofd/brainfuck/xmastree.b) that's only 127 bytes when you delete unnecessary characters.

Comment: the stem of the tree has been misaligned for 12 years

Answer (score 68):

## Perl, 50 chars

(1 relevant spaces)

perl: one line version:

```
print$"x($a-$_),'*'x($_*2+1),$/for 0..($a=pop)-1,0
```

and now with more  whitesapce:

```
print $"  x ( $a - $_ ),             #"# Syntax Highlight Hacking Comment
      '*' x ( $_ * 2  + 1),
      $/
for 0 .. ( $a = pop ) - 1, 0;

$ perl tree.pl 3
   *
  ***
 *****
   *
$ perl tree.pl 11
           *
          ***
         *****
        *******
       *********
      ***********
     *************
    ***************
   *****************
  *******************
 *********************
           *
$
```

#### Expanded Explanation for Non-Perl Users.

```
# print $Default_List_Seperator ( a space )  
#     repeated ( $a - $currentloopiterationvalue ) times,
print $" x ( $a - $_ ), 
#"# print '*' repeated( $currentloopiteration * 2 + 1 ) times. 
  '*' x ( $_ * 2  + 1),
# print $Default_input_record_seperator ( a newline )
  $/
# repeat the above code, in a loop, 
#   iterating values 0 to ( n - 1) , and then doing 0 again
for 0 .. ( $a = pop ) - 1, 0;
# prior to loop iteration, set n to the first item popped off the default list, 
#   which in this context is the parameters passed on the command line.
```

Comment: Smaller perl implementation of same, only 81 chars


    $,="\n";$a=pop;print map{$"x($a-$_).'*'x($_*2+1)}(0...$a-1);print$,.$"x$a."*\n";

Comment: Adding $n=$ARGV[0]; at the beginning (cost = 12 chars), then replacing all subsequent occurrences of $ARGV[0] with $n (savings = 6 chars each, times 3 occurrences) will get you a net 6 character reduction in total length.

Comment: now 79 chars

$,="\n";$a=pop;print map{$"x($a-$_).'*'x($_*2+1)}0...$a-1;print$,.$"x$a."*\n";

Comment: 64: $,="\n";$a=pop;print map{$"x($a-$_).'*'x($_*2+1)}0...$a-1,0,-1;

Comment: 62 $,=$/;$a=pop;print map{$"x($a-$_).'*'x($_*2+1)}0...$a-1,0,-1;

Comment: 56: $a=pop;print map{$"x($a-$_).'*'x($_*2+1).$/}0...$a-1,0;

Comment: 50, but you need to assume perl -E ( 5.10 ) :  $a=pop;say $"x($a-$_).'*'x($_*2+1) for 0...$a-1,0;

Comment: 55, $a=pop;print map{$"x($a-$_).'*'x($_*2+1).$/}0...$a-1,0;

Comment: 52: print $"x($a-$_),'*'x($_*2+1),$/for 0...($a=pop)-1,0

Comment: 50! print$"x($a-$_),'*'x($_*2+1),$/for 0..($a=pop)-1,0

Comment: Holy crap... perl truly is unreadable.

Comment: @zenazn, it seems like that initially, but I would say the same thing about chinese. Once you learn it, it makes perfect sense.

Comment: @zenazn, also, it should be noticed that most golfing is BAD code in any language. If this were a competition for the cleanest code, we could win that too.

Comment: @zenazn: proof, you can see us collaborating and improving each others code above, this proves *WE* can read *EACH OTHERS* code perfectly fine.

Comment: PS: Thanks for the explanation for non-Perl programmers. It's still pretty unreadable, but at least it makes sense. I guess you get used to it after a while.

Comment: someone tipped me off on this one(outputs to stderr, though)
49: warn$"x($a-$_),'*'x($_*2+1),$/for 0..($a=pop)-1,0

Comment: If you are using Perl 5.10, you could replace print, with say.

Comment: Your character count is 49. The space is not significant.

Comment: @Kent. Yes, the same way you can get used to count in binary.  10 + 10  - 11 = ( 100 - 11 ) = 1   ... :-/

Comment: Perl...Is there nothing he can't do

Comment: @zenazn: You haven't seen unreadable until you've seen APL. :-)

Comment: @RobH: J is the child of APL.  In some senses, it's more unreadable because it doesn't use APL's character set with a special symbol for every operation -- it overloads ASCII characters with multiple meanings, instead.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392788/1088931#1088931

Comment: @RobH: You haven't seen unreadable until you've seen Whitespace ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_(programming_language) )

Comment: I point out that the J solution is around half this length...

Comment: Why did this win when J has smaller char count?

Comment: @Claudiu: Look at the dates.  This was accepted *long* before the J solution was written.

Comment: Can be golfed to 44: `say$"x($a-$_),"*"x($_*2+1)for 0..($a=<>)-1,0`, assuming standard input is allowed instead of command line argument. Otherwise, replace `<>` with `pop` and it's 45 chars.

Answer (score 31):

#### Language: Python (through shell), Char count: 64 (2 significant spaces)

```
python -c "
n=w=$1
s=1
while w:
    print' '*w+'*'*s
    s+=2
    w-=1
print' '*n+'*'"

$ sh ax6 11
           *
          ***
         *****
        *******
       *********
      ***********
     *************
    ***************
   *****************
  *******************
 *********************
           *
```

Comment: what I like most about this solution is that python makes it really hard to write obscure code, it's one of the most readable solutions

Comment: You're using the shell to process the argument, which isn't in the spirit of code golf IMO. Using "import sys" and "n=w=int(sys.argv[1])" and an indent of 1 character for the loop body, I come up with 89 characters for this version.

Comment: This is how I did it before. The spirit of this question is to have fun, and in addition there was no specification of using _only_ one language :) See the brainfuck answer, for example; no arguments.

Answer (score 27):

**Language: Windows Batch Script** (*shocking!*)

```
@echo off
echo Enable delayed environment variable expansion with CMD.EXE /V

rem Branches
for /l %%k in (1,1,%1) do (
set /a A=%1 - %%k
set /a B=2 * %%k - 1
set AA=
for /l %%i in (1,1,!A!) do set "AA=!AA! "
set BB=
for /l %%i in (1,1,!B!) do set BB=*!BB!
echo !AA!!BB!
)

rem Trunk
set /a A=%1 - 1
set AA=
for /l %%i in (1,1,!A!) do set "AA=!AA! "
echo !AA!*
```

Comment: masochist! I like it

Comment: Very nice... you get +1

Comment: Delayed variable expansion can be enabled using the `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` command.

Comment: dude. seriously?

Comment: Can't make it work. First time I try though.

Comment: [My answer in batch](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/203596/94029) is much shorter

Answer (score 24):

#### Ruby, 64 bytes

```
n=ARGV[0].to_i
((1..n).to_a+[1]).each{|i|puts' '*(n-i)+'*'*(2*i-1)}
```

```
n=$*[0].to_i
((1..n).to_a<<1).each{|i|puts' '*(n-i)+'*'*(2*i-1)}
```

Merry Christmas all!

Edit: Improvements added as suggested by Joshua Swink

Comment: This is a very nice line of Ruby.

Comment: Did I seem too abrubt? Sorry, not my intention! Merry XMas! :)

Comment: Didn't mean to be mean either, and of course you were right! Merry Xmas!

Comment: I recently found the "Try Ruby" webpage, it looks like such a lovely programming language! :)

Comment: You can replace +[1] with <<1 and ARGV with $* (-3 characters)

Comment: Nice solution. I've translated it to code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392788/1089859#1089859

Comment: On 1.9, you can save some more chars: `n=$*[0].to_i;puts [*1..n,1].map{|i|" "*(n-i)+"*"*(2*i-1)}` brings it down to 58.

Answer (score 17):

#### Language: C#, Char count: 120

```
static void Main(string[] a)
{
    int h = int.Parse(a[0]);

    for (int n = 1; n < h + 2; n++)
        Console.WriteLine(n <= h ?
            new String('*', n * 2 - 1).PadLeft(h + n) :
            "*".PadLeft(h + 1));
    }
}
```

Just the code, without formatting (120 characters):

```
int h=int.Parse(a[0]);for(int n=1;n<h+2;n++)Console.WriteLine(n<=h?new String('*',n*2-1).PadLeft(h+n):"*".PadLeft(h+1));
```

Version with 109 characters (just the code):

```
for(int i=1,n=int.Parse(a[0]);i<n+2;i++)Console.WriteLine(new String('*',(i*2-1)%(n*2)).PadLeft((n+(i-1)%n)));
```

Result for height = 10:

```
          *
         ***
        *****
       *******
      *********
     ***********
    *************
   ***************
  *****************
 *******************
          *
```

Answer (score 16):

**python, "-c" trick... @61 chars (and one line)**

```
python -c"for i in range($1)+[0]:print' '*($1-i)+'*'*(2*i+1)"
```

Comment: Actually, it's 57 characters, only the ' ' space is significant as per the question specifications.

Answer (score 15):

#### Language: dc (through shell) Char count: 83

A little bit shorter dc version:

```
dc -e '?d1rdsv[d32r[[rdPr1-d0<a]dsaxszsz]dsbx1-rd42rlbx2+r10Plv1-dsv0<c]dscxszsz32rlbx[*]p' <<<$1
```

EDIT: changed constant 10 into $1

Comment: Good lord, what the hell is that?

Comment: Just read man page ;-)

Answer (score 14):

Here's a reasonably space-efficient Haskell version, at 107 characters:

```
main=interact$(\g->unlines$map(\a->replicate(g-a)' '++replicate(a*2-1)'*')$[1..g]++[1]).(read::[Char]->Int)
```

running it:

```
$ echo 6 | runhaskell tree.hs
     *
    ***
   *****
  *******
 *********
***********
     *
```

Merry Christmas, all :)

Answer (score 13):

#### Language: dc (through shell), Char count: 119 (1 significant space)

Just for the obscurity of it :)

```
dc -e "$1dsnsm"'
[[ ]n]ss
[[*]n]st
[[
]n]sl
[s2s1[l2xl11-ds10<T]dsTx]sR
[lndlslRxlcdltlRxllx2+sc1-dsn0<M]sM
1sclMxlmlslRxltxllx
'

$ sh ax3 10
          *
         ***
        *****
       *******
      *********
     ***********
    *************
   ***************
  *****************
 *******************
          *
```

Comment: Uhm seriously, wtf? I don't understand a single line of that :P

Comment: dc is a reverse-polish calculator. 'man dc' is the obvious way to go :)

Answer (score 9):

**Groovy**  62B

```
n=args[0]as Long;[*n..1,n].any{println' '*it+'*'*(n-~n-it*2)}
```

_

```
n = args[0] as Long
[*n..1, n].any{ println ' '*it + '*'*(n - ~n - it*2) }
```

Answer (score 9):

Better C++, around 210 chars:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
ostream& ChristmasTree(ostream& os, int height) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= height; ++i) {
        os << string(height-i, ' ') << string(2*i-1, '*') << endl;
    }
    os << string(height-1, ' ') << '*' << endl;
    return os;
}
```

Minimized to 179:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;ostream& xmas(ostream&o,int h){for(int i=1;i<=h;++i){o<<string(h-i,' ')<<string(2*i-1,'*')<<endl;}o<<string(h-1,' ')<<'*'<<endl;return o;}
```

Comment: using std; anyone?

Comment: strager - when I started there were only a couple std::'s and 'using namespace std;' was a lot of text. I suppose now that would be fewer characters.

Comment: Your version is more inefficient than mine, because it has to create strings, my version just prints the characters it needs. :)

Answer (score 9):

Language: python, no tricks, 78 chars

```
import sys
n=int(sys.argv[1])
for i in range(n)+[0]:print' '*(n-i)+'*'*(2*i+1)
```

Answer (score 8):

#### Language: Java, Char count: 219

```
class T{ /* 219 characters */
  public static void main(String[] v){
    int n=new Integer(v[0]);
    String o="";
    for(int r=1;r<=n;++r){
      for(int s=n-r;s-->0;)o+=' ';
      for(int s=1;s<2*r;++s)o+='*';
      o+="%n";}
    while(n-->1)o+=' ';
    System.out.printf(o+"*%n");}}
```

For reference, I was able to shave the previous Java solution, using recursion, down to 231 chars, from the previous minimum of 269. Though a little longer, I do like this solution because `T` is truly object-oriented. You could create a little forest of randomly-sized `T` instances. Here is the latest evolution on that tack:

```
class T{ /* 231 characters */
  public static void main(String[] v){new T(new Integer(v[0]));}}
  String o="";
  T(int n){
    for(int r=1;r<=n;++r){
      x(' ',n-r);x('*',2*r-1);o+="%n";}
    x(' ',n-1);
    System.out.printf(o+"*%n");
  }
  void x(char c,int x){if(x>0){o+=c;x(c,x-1);}
 }
```

Comment: Your new character count is 251 (1 relevant space)

Comment: get rid of "public static void main", use a static block and compile with java 6 ;)

Comment: I know it's been almost 9 years (lol..) but you can golf some things: `class T{public static void main(String[]v){long n=new Long(v[0]),r=1,s;String o="";for(;r<=n;r++){for(s=n-r;s-->0;)o+=' ';for(;++s<2*r;)o+='*';o+="\n";}while(n-->1)o+=' ';System.out.println(o+"*");}}` (199 characters/bytes)

Answer (score 8):

### C# using Linq:

```
    using System;
    using System.Linq;
    class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                int n = int.Parse(args[0]);
                int i=0;
                Console.Write("{0}\n{1}", string.Join("\n", 
                   new int[n].Select(r => new string('*',i * 2 + 1)
                   .PadLeft(n+i++)).ToArray()),"*".PadLeft(n));
            }
       }
```

170 charcters.

```
int n=int.Parse(a[0]);int i=0;Console.Write("{0}\n{1}",string.Join("\n",Enumerable.Repeat(0,n).Select(r=>new string('*',i*2+1).PadLeft(n+i++)).ToArray()),"*".PadLeft(n));
```

Answer (score 7):

Improving ΤΖΩΤΖΙΟΥ's answer. I can't comment, so here is a new post. 72 characters.

```
import sys
n=int(sys.argv[1])
for i in range(n)+[0]:
   print ("*"*(2*i+1)).center(2*n)
```

Using the "python -c" trick, 61 characters.

```
python -c "
for i in range($1)+[0]:
   print ('*'*(2*i+1)).center(2*$1)
"
```

I learned the center function and that "python -c" can accept more than one line code. Thanks, 
ΤΖΩΤΖΙΟΥ.

Answer (score 7):

AWK, 86 characters on one line.

```
awk '{s="#";for(i=0;i<$1;i++){printf"%"$1-i"s%s\n","",s;s=s"##"}printf"%"$1"s#\n",""}'

echo "8" | awk '{s="#";for(i=0;i<$1;i++){printf"%"$1-i"s%s\n","",s;s=s"##"}printf"%"$1"s#\n",""}'
        #
       ###
      #####
     #######
    #########
   ###########
  #############
 ###############
        #

cat tree.txt
3
5

awk '{s="#";for(i=0;i<$1;i++){printf"%"$1-i"s%s\n","",s;s=s"##"}printf"%"$1"s#\n",""}' tree.txt
   #
  ###
 #####
   #
     #
    ###
   #####
  #######
 #########
     #
```

Answer (score 7):

21 characters with dyalog APL.

```
m,⍨⌽0 1↓m←↑'*'\¨⍨1,⍨⍳
```

⍳ gives a vector of integers starting with 1.

1,⍨ adds a one to the end of the vector. This will be the foot of the tree.

'*'\¨⍨ gives a vector of *-strings with lengths given by the previous vector.

↑  transforms the vector to a matrix and adds spaces to the right.

m← stores the matrix in m.

0 1↓ drops zero rows and the first column.

⌽ reverses the matrix.

m,⍨ concatenates with m at the right side.

Comment: `m,⍨⌽0 1↓m←` -> `(⌽,0 1↓⊢)`

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>54</s> <s>53</s> 52 bytes

This is shorter than [@xnor's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/177755/88546) by 4 bytes.

```python
i=n=input()
while~i:i-=1;print i%n*' '+~i%n*'**'+'*'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9M2zzYzr6C0REOTqzwjMye1LtMqU9fW0LqgKDOvRCFTNU9LXUFduw7M0NJS11bXUv//3wwA)

---

I borrowed @xnor's trick of using modulo (`i%n`) in order to print the trunk on the last line. The next part is figuring out how to print the number of stars.

```python
   i   | ~i%n | *2+1 |
-------|------|------|
   5   |   0  |   1  |
   4   |   1  |   3  |
   3   |   2  |   5  |
   2   |   3  |   7  |
   1   |   4  |   9  |
   0   |   5  |  11  |
  -1   |   0  |   1  |
```

The example above illustrates the number of stars we need to print given our variable \$i\$. First, we 'invert' \$i\$ by doing `~i%n`. This gives us an increasing sequence starting from 0. Keep in mind that the way Python handles negative modulo is different from other languages like C.

Answer (score 6):

**Language:PowerShell, Char count: 41 (including 1 space)**

```
1..$args[0]+1|%{" "*(30-$_)+"*"*($_*2-1)}
```

Answer (score 5):

#### Language: C, Char count: 133

Improvement of the C-version.

```
char s[61];

l(a,b){printf("% *.*s\n",a,b,s);}

main(int i,char**a){
  int n=atoi(a[1]);memset(s,42,61);
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)l(i+n,i*2+1);l(n,1);
}
```

Works and even takes the tree height as an argument. Needs a compiler that tolerates K&R-style code.

I feel so dirty now.. This is code is ugly.

Comment: This has the same problem as my first cut in Java; it isn't a complete program with use of a command-line argument!

Comment: Oh? Is this required? 

No problem. I'll fix that.

Comment: It's 138 characters when all unnecessary newlines are removed.

Comment: I count 133 (just removed all whitespace and checked the filesize)

Answer (score 4):

#### Language: Python, Significant char count: 90

It's ugly but it works:

```
import sys
n=int(sys.argv[1])
print"\n".join(" "*(n-r-1)+"*"*(r*2+1)for r in range(n)+[0])
```

...

```
$ python tree.py 13
            *
           ***
          *****
         *******
        *********
       ***********
      *************
     ***************
    *****************
   *******************
  *********************
 ***********************
*************************
            *
```

Comment: Your character count is 98 (2 significant spaces, those in quotes)

Answer (score 4):

#### Language: C, Char count: 176 (2 relevant spaces)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define P(x,y,z) for(x=0;x++<y-1;)printf(z);
main(int c,char **v){int i,j,n=atoi(v[1]);for(i=0;i<n;i++){P(j,n-i," ")P(j,2*i+2,"*")printf("\n");}P(i,n," ")printf("*\n");}
```

Answer (score 4):

Shell version, 134 characters:

```
#!/bin/sh
declare -i n=$1
s="*"
for (( i=0; i<$n; i++ )); do
    printf "%$(($n+$i))s\n" "$s"
    s+="**"
done
printf "%$(($n))s\n" "*"
```

Comment: [golfed down to 70 bytes](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v9g2Rss6Lb9IQ8M600bF0DpTW1tTs1qhoCgzryRNQVUlWsVQOzO2OCYmT0Gl2LpY21ZJS0vJupYLrsCwWCFG6////2YA) :)

Answer (score 4):

### R (62 bytes)

I did not see R solution yet. Correct me if I missed it.

```
for(i in c(1:N,1))cat(rep(" ",N-i),rep("*",2*i-1),"\n",sep="")
```

Output:

```
> N <- 3
> for(i in c(1:N,1))cat(rep(" ",N-i),rep("*",2*i-1),"\n",sep="")
  *
 ***
*****
  *
> 
> N <- 4
> for(i in c(1:N,1))cat(rep(" ",N-i),rep("*",2*i-1),"\n",sep="")
   *
  ***
 *****
*******
   *
> 
> N <- 5
> for(i in c(1:N,1))cat(rep(" ",N-i),rep("*",2*i-1),"\n",sep="")
    *
   ***
  *****
 *******
*********
    *
```

Answer (score 4):

### J, 24

Works akin to the [accepted answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4293/3918) in that you include the parameter in the source code.  Expressing it as a proper function would be slightly longer.  Uses a different approach than the accepted answer.

```
' *'#~(>:@+:,.~#-])0,~i.
```

E.g.

```
   ' *' #~ (>:@+: ,.~ #-]) 0 ,~ i.5
    *    
   ***   
  *****  
 ******* 
*********
    *
```

As a function (**27**):

```
#&' *'@(>:@+:,.~#-])@,&0@i.
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

```
R”*ẋz⁶ṚŒBṁ‘Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASQA2/9qZWxsef//UuKAnSrhuot64oG24bmaxZJC4bmB4oCYWf///zU)

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, 111 chars

(The very last char should be a newline.)

```
<?php $n=$argv[1];for($r='str_repeat';$i<$n;$i++)echo $r(' ',$n-$i).$r('*',$i*2+1)."\n";echo $r(' ',$n).'*' ?>
```

Readable version:

```
<?php

$n = $argv[1];

for ($r = 'str_repeat'; $i < $n; $i++)
    echo $r(' ', $n - $i) . $r('*' , $i * 2 + 1) . "\n";

echo $r(' ', $n) . '*'

?>
```

Comment: You can save several characters by building the string, then echoing it.  I think.  Try that out.

Comment: Good idea, but I tried it and it only makes it longer. '$t.=(...)' is only one char shorter than 'echo (...)', and then you'd have to 'echo $t' at the end as well.

Comment: Shortened it by 4 chars by removing the '$i = 0;' first part of the for statement. PHP assumes that nonexistent variables used in an integer context are 0 already! :P

Comment: Saved a char by putting $r=.. inside the for.  Also, I say newline characters should be one byte, not two.  =]

Comment: Yeah I just realized I miscounted by one because I counted using the column number in my text editor. I use linux so the newline char is one byte.

Answer (score 3):

Java version. 189 character

```
class P
{
 static String p(int n, String s) 
 {
  return --n < 1 ? s : p(n, s) + s;
 }

 public static void main(String[] a) 
 {
  for (int N = new Integer(a[0]), i = -1; i++ < N;) 
   System.out.println(p(N - i % N, " ") + p(i % N * 2 + 1, "*"));
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**C# - Recursion**

```
using System;

class A
{
    static string f(int n, int r)
    {
        return "\n".PadLeft(2 * r, '*').PadLeft(n + r) 
            + (r < n ? f(n, ++r) : "*".PadLeft(n));
    }

    static void Main(string[] a)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(f(int.Parse(a[0]), 1));
    }
}
```

**177 chars** (not as short the other C# method posted, but a different way of doing it).

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 9 bytes

```
Ｇ↗↘←Ｎ*Ｍ↓*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/charcoal#ARsA5P//77yn4oaX4oaY4oaQ77yuKu@8reKGkyr//zU)

### Verbose

```
Polygon(:UpRight, :DownRight, :Left, InputNumber(), "*")
Move(:Down)
Print("*")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/charcoal#@x@Qn1OZnp@nYRVaEJSZnlGio2Dlkl@eB2P7pKYBKc@8gtISv9LcpNQiDU0dBSUtJU0u3/yyVA2wWk2ugKLMvBINkPD//6b/dcsA)

Comment: [8 bytes](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMMqtEBHQUlLSdOaKyA/pzI9P0/Dyic1rURHASgTlJmeAWK55JfnQdmeeQWlJX6luUmpRRqaUJ3//5v@1y3LAQA)

Comment: Why is this non-competing?

Comment: this was before the rule change to allow languages made after the question; feel free to edit it

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
LĆ'*×j€û»
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f50ibutbh6VmPmtYc3n1o9///JgA) or [verify all Christmas trees in the range [3, 30]](https://tio.run/##ASkA1v9vc2FiaWX/MzDCrHPFuHZ5w5As/0zEhicqw5dq4oKsw7vCu/8swrY//w).

`€û»` can alternatively be `».º` for the same byte-count: [try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f50ibutbh6VmHdusd2vX/vwkA).

**9 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) alternative:**

```
·ÅÉĆ'*×.c
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0PbDrYc7j7Spax2erpf8/78JAA) or [verify all Christmas trees in the range [3, 30]](https://tio.run/##ASgA1/9vc2FiaWX/MzDCrHPFuHZ5w5As/8K3w4XDicSGJyrDly5j/yzCtj//).

**Explanation:**

```python
L          # Create a list in the range [1, (implicit) input]
           #  i.e. 3 → [1,2,3]
 Ć         # Enclose; appending its own head
           #  → [1,2,3,1]
  '*×     '# For each value, repeat the "*" that many times as string
           #  → ["*","**","***","*"]
     j     # Prepend spaces to make all items of a length equal to the (implicit) input
           #  → ["  *"," **","***","  *"]
      €û   # Palindromize each string
           #  → ["  *  "," *** ","*****","  *  "]
        »  # Join the list by newlines
           #  → "  *  \n *** \n*****\n  *  "
           # (after which it is output implicitly as result)

·          # Double the (implicit) input-integer
           #  i.e. 3 → 6
 ÅÉ        # Pop and push a list of all odd numbers <= this integer
           #  → [1,3,5]
   Ć       # Enclose; appending its own head
           #  → [1,3,5,1]
    '*×   '# For each value, repeat the "*" that many times as string
           #  → ["*","***","*****","*"]
       .c  # Centralize it by adding leading spaces (which implicitly joins by newlines)
           #  → "  *\n ***\n*****\n  *"
           # (after which it is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 3):

## c: <strike>151</strike> <strike>116</strike> 115

Just giving it a whirl

```
i,j,a;main(c,v)int**v;{for(a=atoi(v[1]);i<a;i+=puts(""))for(j=0;j<a+i;)putchar(++j<a-i?32:42);printf("%*s",a,"*");}
```

Readable code:

```
i, j, a; 
main(c, v) int **v; {
    for (a = atoi(v[1]); i < a; i += puts(""))
        for(j = 0; j < a + i;)
            putchar(++j < a - i ? 32 : 42);
    printf("%*s", a, "*");
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcxBCsIwEEDRuwwIM0kKWrtyGjyIdDEEqhOwLWnMRjx7TLePzw/dM4Ra1UUn/BZdMLhCumRjCn/nNaF4yatieVwmYh2F1frtk3cEIDqC6M8cR7HK1Dy8JKG1DTq9X/vb0BNvqQ1nhJPZwYkDA8S/WuvwBw)

## Code History:

```
main(int c, char **v){
    int i, j, a = atoi(v[1]);
    for (i = 1; i <= a; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < a + i - 1; j++)
            putchar((j >= a - i) ? '*' : ' ');
        putchar('\n');
    }
    printf("%*s*\n", a - 1, "");
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! This is good for a first submission; however, I see some easy improvements you can make by simply removing unnecessary spaces and newlines. Also, can you provide a link to test this? It's missing `#include<stdio.h>` and I'm getting segfaults: [link](https://tio.run/##Tc5LDoIwEAbgPaf4gzEtpRhJXAniQcRFUx8M0WIQ3BjPXgdU4izaZOabh03O1no/I2cv/eGI/N4dqFlURXA15CS5DlbDVqaFUo/oGYBjyJJGrWGwgekako9duo@ysXpqWkjiQpqBkDPgP44jfJonUjNZZqiR85iYaTJ01CwnN8St74b1kn3Bs1hRhC2EElhDQHy3/lNRul/6Nb63lk8@yXCu7qp0oR7HpBphyOzl/eoN)

Comment: I think you're getting segfaults because you provided the number as an input rather than an argument [link](https://tio.run/##Tc5LCsIwEAbgvaf4CUgeTcGCK1v1INZFCFQTMC1t7UZ69jipWpxFAjPfPGx@szbGh3FBuDDCati76aHUJF8bUKSs0/AaBkeYsXViuhRXWS7Vpu0hHBWKEg4VAfqzTOLTvBJPZFfCo6IxGdE8dXiSq0vRPce0XpA/0SxSTuIMrjgO4ODfrf@U1@GXnpe36@nkRrCtGlQdmF7GFBqMEZtjjPs3) You also don't *have* to include the `#include` the compiler will yell at you but it will work. I left in the spaces because the challenge said to count characters ignoring whitespace and it makes it more readable

Comment: Oh okay. That makes sense, sorry not a C user :P Thanks for the explanation. And yeah, my bad, I forgot about that part of this challenge (haven't visited it in a while).

Comment: You can save another byte with `++j<a-i`

Answer (score 3):

## [Poetic](https://mcaweb.matc.edu/winslojr/vicom128/final/index.html), 547 bytes

```
the triangle trees
a december i loved
o,i placed a fun christmasy thing
i know i am hoping on a santa,a gift,cookie plates,or bag o dolls
i know i am choosing my toy to expect of him,Mr.Claus
i say,Mr,i think i may ask nicely
we are nice people,we are
o,under the tree i go crazy as i glance at the a-b-c puzzle we got
a thing on Xmas i am happy to be toying with
o,i found it!for a moment,i shouted thanks
a gift i am having as we enjoy a holiday feast
and now i sleep
oh,here i am,silent as i could
i quickly awaken
i then go to locate a present
```

[Try it online!](https://mcaweb.matc.edu/winslojr/vicom128/final/tio/index.html?VVExUsQwDOzzCtEHZuAL1PS0iqPEJrZlbOfC3eePVW4oKDxjydrV7rp7oV4D5zXaRaQNTLM4SZNUChT1IvOgY6AS2clMTMueyfkaWk/crtR9yOsQaMt6AMCJvBa0SDOGG@fOI9Malj461S2IMXVpo1aaGGM0a4ztH4Pzqs04EvjVDslPEddJF/IhjR/15T3ybqjGV5QQaEI24BNfidtGOTiJ1@EQ4ipnRUW0RBkfLbja8wyX3T@sA7squco3I7AqcgaK@znCz9Ozo7LfbogKFKt2ZHXaN6@f6cSYfy7l1DyJqbf3I3R/prgodlLoTwvsMyVNkjv6zeveEW/3nDf7Awvsj@5iFGDHUslfyIORcQwzjC7CDTLA@QivRZEyqB@9VDnxYwsROx6OnO5xRmjfe3BbBNHBm@TBwpNs7qE6qsP/YEep0oC8v77dJ55/AQ)

Translated from [a version by Daniel Cristofani](http://www.hevanet.com/cristofd/brainfuck/xmastree.b), but optimized specifically for program length in Poetic (more groups of `>` than `<`, more groups of `+` than `-`, etc).

Answer (score 3):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), <s>33</s> 29 bytes

```
{(x+1)#(-x+!x)$(1+2*!x)#'"*"}
```

-4 thanks to streetser!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P82qWqNC21BTWUO3QluxQlNFw1DbSAvIUFZX0lKq/Z@mYP4fAA)

Comment: 29 bytes - `{(x+1)#(-x+!x)$(1+2*!x)#'"*"}`

Comment: @streetster, thanks. updated

Comment: Can drop another byte by forgoing the `$` pad: `{" *"(x+1)#(|!x)(&,)'1+2*!x}`

Answer (score 3):

## Scala 3, char count <del>132</del> 124

```scala
@main def t(n:Int)={def p(i:Int,j:Int):Unit={println(" "*i+"*"*j);if(i==0)println(" "*(j/2)+"*");else p(i-1,j+2);};p(n-1,1)}
```

#### Readable version

```scala
@main def t(n:Int) = 
  def p(i:Int, j:Int):Unit = 
    println(" " * i + "*" * j)
    if (i == 0) println(" " * (j / 2) + "*")
    else p(i - 1, j + 2)
  p(n - 1, 1)
```

#### Results

```
scala xmastree.scala 3
  *
 ***
*****
  *

scala xmastree.scala 5
    *
   ***
  *****
 *******
*********
    *
```

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833), and nice first answer! Can you shorten your code by removing the spaces/indentation?

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Comment: In general we score answers in bytes, not characters. In this case the value seems to be the same.

Answer (score 3):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 67 bytes

```
1:{:v :,2+1{1p461<
v!?:<-1o*84
\~$
>:?!v67*o1-
+:}}\0?;~ao1-::?!v{2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/39Cq2qpMwUrHSNuw2rDAxMzQhqtM0d7KRtcwX8vChCumToXLzspesczMXCvfUJdL26q2NsbA3rouEcizAklUG/3//1@3zBQA)

Answer (score 2):

#### Language: Erlang, Char count: 183 (2 relevant spaces)

Here is an Erlang version, ~181chars:

```
-module (x).
-export ([t/1]).

t(N) ->
 t(N,0).
t(0,N) ->
 io:format("~s~s~n",[string:copies(" ",N),"*"]);
t(H,S) ->
 io:format("~s~s~n",[string:copies(" ",H),string:copies("*",(S*2)+1)]),
 t(H-1,S+1).
```

(btw, happy Christmas to everyone!)

Answer (score 2):

#### Language: C, Char count: 433 (1 relevant space)

C version. Not short, not pretty, but it works.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printLevel(int level, int width)
{
    int i;
    int count = level + (level - 1);
    int spaces = width - count;
    int lowerBound = spaces / 2;
    int upperBound = width - lowerBound;
    for (i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        if (i >= lowerBound && i < upperBound) {
            printf("*");
        } else {
            printf(" ");
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void makeTree(int level)
{
    int i;
    int width = level * 2 - 1;
    for (i = 1; i <= level; i++) {
        printLevel(i, width);
    }
    printLevel(1, width);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int level = atoi(argv[1]);
    makeTree(level);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Language: Nemerle+Nextem, Char count: 129 (1 relevant space)

Nemerle with Nextem:

```
type s=string;
module t {
    public Main(a : array[s]) : void {
     def t = int.Parse(a[0]);
     def x(i) { print s(' ',t-i) + s('*',i*2+1) }
     $[0..t].Iter(x);
     x(0)
    }
}
```

Char count: 128

Edit:  Made it take an arg
Edit2: Imperative now

Answer (score 2):

#### Language: Scala, Char count: 128 (1 relevant space)

My **Scala** version.
I'm glad I have found the * operator for strings (String implicitly promoted to RichString).

```
  def tree(n:Int) {
    def vals(n:Int,k:Int) = ((1 to n) map { i => (k - i, (i * 2) - 1) }).toList
    for(j <- vals(n,n) ::: vals(1,n)) 
      println(" " * j._1 + "*" * j._2)
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would do it in **Python**, very straightforward, only 103 characters:

```
import sys
n=int(sys.argv[1])
for i in range(n): print ('*'*(2*i+1)).center(2*n)
print '*'.center(2*n)
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, 110 characters (2 relevant spaces)

```
function p(l)
{
    o=''
    for(c=0; c<=n+l; c++)
      o += c < n - l ? ' ' : '*'
    print(o)
}

n = parseInt(arguments[0])

for(l = 0; l < n; l++)
  p(l)
p(0)
```

Ran using spidermonkey.
$ smjs christmas_tree.js 4

### For Javascript Console 105

```
function p(l){o='';for(c=0;c<=n+l;)o+=c++<n-l?' ':'*';console.log(o)}n=+prompt();for(l=0;l<n;)p(l++);p(0)
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP (133 relevant characters):

```
function xmastree($h) {
    for($i=0;$i<$h;++$i)
        echo str_repeat(' ',$h-$i-1).str_repeat('*',2*$i+1)."\n";
    echo str_repeat(' ',$h-1)."*\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Language: C, Char count: 116**

I realized I could improve on my original design:

```
main(int c,char**v){char l[99],i=0;for(c=atoi(1[v]);i<c;printf("%*s%.*s\n",c,l,i++,l))l[i]=42;printf("%*c\n",c,42);}
```

Different approach (119 characters):

```
s[99],w,i=0;p(n){printf("%*.*s\n",w+n,n*2+1,s);}main(int c,char**v){w=atoi(v[1]);for(memset(s,42,99);i<w;p(i++));p(0);}
```

Old version (123 characters):

```
main(int c,char**v){char*l=calloc(c=atoi(v[1]),2),i=0;for(;i<c;printf("%*s%.*s\n",c,l,i++,l))l[i]=42;printf("%*c\n",c,42);}
```

(One byte can be saved by putting `char *l=...` in the `for` loop.  That makes it non-standard, however (though `gcc` still accepts it).)

Answer (score 2):

Common Lisp, 117 essential characters:

```
(defun x (n)
  (dotimes (v n)
    (format t "~v:@<~v{*~}~>~%"
            (1- (* 2 n))
            (1+ (* 2 v))
            '(())))
  (format t "~v:@<*~>~%" (1-(* 2 n)))
```

Are there any `format` gurus out there who know a better way to get repeating arbitrary characters?

Answer (score 2):

**Language: Php, Char count: 110 (3 relevant spaces)**

<?
function x($n,$a,$t){return $n?str_repeat(' ',$n).$a.x($n-1,"**$a"," $t"):$t;}echo x($argv[1],"*\n","*\n");

A bit of php recursion to reduce the count of chars to 110.

Answer (score 2):

FreePascal:

```
program xmastree;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

uses
  {$IFDEF UNIX}{$IFDEF UseCThreads}
  cthreads,
  {$ENDIF}{$ENDIF}
  Classes
  { you can add units after this };

var x,y,h:integer;

{$IFDEF WINDOWS}{$R xmastree.rc}{$ENDIF}

procedure printRow(sp,st:integer);
var i:integer;
begin
    for i := 1 to sp do begin
    write(' ');
  end;
    for x := 1 to st do begin
    write('*');
  end;
    for x := 1 to sp do begin
    write(' ');
  end;
    writeln();
end;

begin
    val(ParamStr(1),h);
  for y := 1 to h do begin
    printRow(h-y,(y-1)*2+1);
  end;
  printRow(h-1,1);
end.
```

Output for xmastree.exe 9

```
        *
       ***
      *****
     *******
    *********
   ***********
  *************
 ***************
*****************
        *
```

Answer (score 2):

## Windows Batch File

Windows batch files have poor support for string operations: they can concatename, extract and replace strings, but generation of arbitrary-length strings according to a certain pattern AFAIK can only be done via loops. This is how [Zach Scrivena](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392788/code-golf-christmas-edition-how-to-print-out-a-christmas-tree-of-height-n/393677#393677)'s solution works.

However, one can notice that the *N+1*-th tree line can be generated from the *N*-th line by cutting one leading space off and adding two traling asterisks, which pretty much simplifies the task. Also, the tree truck repeats the tree top so we can re-use that string to get rid of a few extra loops. So, here's my batch file that uses these two tricks (**165** characters):

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set s=
for /l %%i in (1,1,%1)do set s= !s!
set t=!s!*
for /l %%i in (1,1,%1)do echo !t!&set t=!t:~1!**
echo %s%*
```

Assuming that echo is already off and command extensions and delayed variable expansion are on, we can drop the first two lines and shorten the code down to **108** characters.

Usage:

```
> xmastree.bat 7 & pause
       * 
      *** 
     ***** 
    ******* 
   ********* 
  *********** 
 ************* 
       *
```

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell - <strike>105</strike> 95 characters - 3 Relevant spaces

Improved on the other Haskell solution (https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4267/7353) by <strike>2</strike> 12 strokes.

- Updated `take x$cycle "*"` into `replicate x '*'`
- Removed unnecessary brackets

Updated version:

```
r=replicate;main=(\x->mapM_ putStrLn[r(x-l)' '++r(l+l-1)'*'|l<-[1..x]++[1]])=<<(readLn::IO Int)
```

Previous version:

```
c=cycle;main=(\x->mapM_ putStrLn[(take(x-l)$c" ")++(take(l+l-1)$c"*")|l<-[1..x]++[1]])=<<(readLn::IO Int)
```

Readable (updated) version:

```
main=(\ size->
          mapM_
               putStrLn
               [replicate (size - count) ' ' ++ replicate (count + count - 1) '*' | count <- [1..size] ++ [1]]
     ) =<< ( readLn :: IO Int )
```

Haskell is such an elegant language.

Answer (score 2):

It's in **PHP**.

```
<center><?$t=$_GET[1]*2-$i=1;while($i<=$t){echo str_repeat('*',$i).'<br>';$i+=2;}echo'*'?><center>
```

Total characters(with spaces):**98**
Total characters(with no spaces):**97**
Bytes:**98**

Answer (score 2):

**K 33**

```
q)k)f:{{(|:'x),'1_'x}x$(1+(!x),0)#'"*"}
q)f 4
"   *   "
"  ***  "
" ***** "
"*******"
"   *   "
```

Answer (score 2):

### Bash: <s>126</s>120

As there is no [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) purpose, there is one:

```
for((z=$1-1;z;z--)){ printf -v s "%$((($1-z)*2-1))s" ""
printf "%$((2*$1-z))s\n" "${s// /*}";};printf "%$((1+$1))s\n" \*
```

This could be written:

```
#!/bin/bash
               #
              for\
            ((z=$1-
          1;z;z--));do
        printf -v s "%$((
     ($1-z)*2-1))s" "" #fil
   printf "%$((2*$1-z))s\n" \
 "${s// /*}";done;printf "%$((1
          +$1))s\n"\
              \*
              ##
```

#### In use:

```
set -- 12
for((z=$1-1;z;z--)){ printf -v s "%$((($1-z)*2-1))s" ""
printf "%$((2*$1-z))s\n" "${s// /*}";};printf "%$((1+$1))s\n" \*
            *
           ***
          *****
         *******
        *********
       ***********
      *************
     ***************
    *****************
   *******************
  *********************
            *
```

### Or into the script:

```
./chrismas.sh 6
      *
     ***
    *****
   *******
  *********
      *
```

Comment: [another bash solution](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v9g2Rss6Lb9IQ8M600bF0FpTs1qhoCgzryRNQVUlWsVQO1NbO7Y4JiZPQaXYuljbVklLS8m6lguuxLBYIUbr////ZgA) squished down to 69 bytes :)

Comment: nice! Publish, I will give you my upvote!

Comment: (U could save 1 char by using `\**` instead of `"**"`! ;)

Answer (score 2):

## Python - 104 / 94 characters

Alright, so I have two solutions here. One of them is, I guess, a bit "trickier", placing all of the code on one line, while the other solution is actually shorter.

```
import sys
c=int(sys.argv[1])
for i in range(c+2):print" "*(c-1)+"*"if i==c+1 else" "*(c-i)+"*"*(2*i-1)
```

That's the 104-char version. Who said python is always readable? It doesn't use any "tricks" though, which is a plus, I guess? If we split the if/else statement onto a seperate line like so:

```
import sys
c=int(sys.argv[1])
for i in range(c+1):print" "*(c-i)+"*"*(2*i-1)
print" "*(c-1)+"*"
```

...this is much neater and is actually a few characters shorter.

Answer (score 2):

## Python-3x, 119 bytes

```
N = int(input())
print(' '*N+'\n','\n'.join(['\t'+' '*(N-i)+'*'*(i*2+1) for i in range(N)]) + '\n', ' '*(N+3)+'*'+'\n')
```

result:-

```
enter N value
3
   *
  ***
 *****
   *



 4
        *
       ***
      *****
     *******
        *

9
             *
            ***
           *****
          *******
         *********
        ***********
       *************
      ***************
     *****************
             *
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! The point of challenges like this one is to provide a solution in as few bytes as possible, so you should include in the title how long it is. (I'd recommend pasting it into [this byte counter](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter).) Speaking of which, you could shave off 25 bytes by removing the `print` statement at the beginning and removing the spaces around the `=` sign.

Comment: Ok, but this is not Python 2.7 anymore, but Python 3. ;) The remaining issue is that your code generates one size smaller tree than specified.

Comment: I mentioned it as python-2.7 because in my systems library I have python-2.7 and in my virtualenvironment I have python 3.4. When I execute python 2.7 in the editor I get errors for example if I try end=' ' in the print function if I want to print anything in single line. I import from __future__ to enable print functions which are active in python 3.x versions. Also I have made minor change to represent correct size of tree.

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), 58 bytes

```js
f=(n,s=`*
`,l)=>n?(k=' '.repeat(--n)+s)+f(n,'**'+s,l||k):l
```

#### Demo

```js
f=(n,s=`*
`,l)=>n?(k=' '.repeat(--n)+s)+f(n,'**'+s,l||k):l

console.log(f(7))
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2 - 62 Bytes:

```
i,x=input()*2,1
exec"print('*'*(x%i)).center(i);x+=2;"*(i/2+1)
```

Multiplying the input by two saves a byte because of the need for extra brackets.
There may be a way to further golf the operations.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 56 bytes

```python
i=n=input()
exec"i=~-i%n;print' '*i+'*'*(n*2-i+~i);"*-~n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9M2zzYzr6C0REOTK7UiNVkp07ZON1M1z7qgKDOvRF1BXStTW11LXUsjT8tIN1O7LlPTWklLty7v/38zAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 39 bytes

```perl6
{say " "x$^a-$_,\*x$_*2-1 for 1...$a,1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwv7o4sVJBSUGpQiUuUVclXidGq0IlXstI11AhLb9IwVBPT08lUcew9n@ahrGmNVeahgmYNDbQtP4PAA)

It's one of those questions, where it's easier to just print the lines in the code block.

#### Explanation:

```perl6
{say " "x$^a-$_,\*x$_*2-1 for 1...$a,1}
{                                     }   # Anonymous code block
                          for 1...$a,1    # Loop over 1 to n and 1 again
 say                                      # Print
     " "x$^a-$_                           # Leading spaces
               ,\*x$_*2-1                 # And then the amount of asterisks
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/fb4a2ce2bce6660e1a680a74dd61b72c945e6c3b), <s>16</s> 10 bytes

```
L·<'**Ć.c»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f59B2G3UtrSNtesmHdv//b/JfNwUA)

### Explanation:

```
L·<'**Ć.c»
L          : Create a range [1..input]
 ·<        : 2n-1 every element
   '**     : Multiply every element with "*"
      Ć    : Append the first element to the end
       .c  : Centralize elements
         » : Print out with newlines
```

## Previous solution:

```
µ¾·>'**¼})Ć.c»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASYA2f8wNWFiMWX//8K1wr7Ctz4nKipJwr4tw7rCvH0pxIbCu///NP8tZA)

### Explanation:

```
µ¾·>'**I¾-ú¼})Ć»
 ¾·>'**I¾-ú      : Create the row with padding and push to stack
           ¼     : Increment the counter
µ           }    : Loop until the counter reaches the input
             )   : Enclose stack to a list
              Ć  : Append the head to the end
               » : Print out the stack with newlines
```

Comment: No need to mark as noncompeting

Answer (score 2):

**Intel [4004](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_4004) machine code**, 59 bytes

This 4-bit chip was the first commercial microprocessor, introduced in 1971. Multiplication and division were performed in software, and the accumulator could not be copied to one of the 16 registers except by swapping values.

```
40 33 50 0F A0 F8 B0 A0 1C 02 A1 B0 50 0F C0 24
20 A0 F8 50 2B 24 2A A1 90 F5 50 2B 24 20 A0 F8
50 2B 24 0C 53 E0 24 0D 53 E0 C0 14 32 53 E0 F8
40 2B C0 53 F0 B3 B0 A0 B1 50 02
```

The assembly code requires this [python emulator](https://github.com/CodeAbbey/intel4004-emu) for meaningful output.

```
jun start

mainloop:
    jms printline
    ld r0
    dac
    xch r0
    ld r0
    jcn an mainloop
    ld r1
    xch r0
    jms printline
    bbl 0

printline:
    fim r2 32
    ld r0
    dac
    jms printx

    fim r2 42
    ld r1
    sub r0
    ral
    jms printx

    fim r2 32
    ld r0
    dac
    jms printx

    ;carriage return
    fim r2 12
    jms $3e0
    fim r2 13
    jms $3e0

    bbl 0

printx: 
    jcn az ditch
    jms $3e0
    dac
    jun printx
ditch:
    bbl 0

start:
    jms $3f0 ; input
    xch r3
    xch r0 ; running total
    ld r0
    xch r1 ; permanent total
    jms mainloop
```

Sample run:

```
$ python intel4004-emu/main.py tree.4004 
8
       *       
      ***      
     *****     
    *******    
   *********   
  ***********  
 ************* 
***************
       *
```

Answer (score 2):

### Batch, <s>132</s> 129 bytes

```
@!! 2>nul||cmd/q/v/c%0 %1&&exit/b
for /l %%X in (1 1 %1)do set[= ![!
set]=![!*
:*
echo%]%
set]=%]:~1%**
2>x goto:*%]:~1%&echo%[%*
```

I shamelessly copied [Golfing Delayed Expansion Variables in Batch](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54228/golfing-delayed-expansion-variables-in-batch) to my batch script.
Uses the [bizarre ability](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6491) of `GOTO :NUL` to

> allow execution of concatenated commands in the context of the caller

Edit 2020/5/1: Abused token delimiters to shorten variable names

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `C`, 7 bytes

```
ʁd›×*×J
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=C&code=%CA%81d%E2%80%BA%C3%97*%C3%97J&inputs=4&header=&footer=)

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 13 bytes

```
ɾ×*§↵vøm:⁋₴h,
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C9%BE%C3%97*%C2%A7%E2%86%B5v%C3%B8m%3A%E2%81%8B%E2%82%B4h%2C&inputs=4&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 2):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) `-r`, <s>47</s> <s>41</s> 39 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to [Michael Chatiskatzi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/90812/michael-chatiskatzi)*

```
. as$n|range(.),0|" "*($n-.)+"**"*.+"*"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/19PIbFYJa@mKDEvPVVDT1PHoEZJQUlLQyVPV09TW0lLS0lLD0gp/f9v@i@/oCQzP6/4v24RAA) Add 2 bytes if a leading space is not acceptable.

```
. as$n                                   Store the input number in $n
      |                                  With that number as .
       range(.)                           Numbers from 0 up to one less than .
               ,0                         and also another 0
                 |                       With each of those numbers as .
                     *($n-.)              $n minus . copies of
                  " "                     space
                            +             Concatenate
                                 *.       . copies of
                             "**"         that string
                                   +"*"   Concatenate one more asterisk
```

The `-r` flag outputs each of those strings on a separate line without wrapping it in quotes.

Comment: `range(.),0` will save 2 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

#### Language: Python, Char count: 104

Another take at python. Note that the question requested for a script, not a function.

```
import sys
n= int(sys.argv[1])
c= lambda s: s.center(2*n)
print "\n".join(c("*"*(2*i+1)) for i in range(n)); print c("*")

$ py ax 11
          *
         ***
        *****
       *******
      *********
     ***********
    *************
   ***************
  *****************
 *******************
*********************
          *
```

Answer (score 1):

First try in LUA

```
f=string.rep p=print function t(N) for i=0,N do s=f(" ",N-i) p(s..f("+",2*i-1)..s) end p(f(" ",N-1).."+"..f(" ",N-1)) end t(arg[1])
```

After selecting all of it scite tells me these are 131 chars

For clarities sake without optimizing away the \n etc:

```
f=string.rep 
p=print 
function t(N) 
 for i=0,N do 
   s=f(" ",N-i)
   p(s..f("+",2*i-1)..s)
 end 
  p(f(" ",N-1).."+"..f(" ",N-1)) 
end 
t(arg[1])
```

For the python version by ΤΖΩΤΖΙΟΥ I get shown 115 chars... Hrm, some more things to optimize

Comment: Note: all insignificant/irrelevant whitespace should be ignored, as per the question specifications. So, any beautifying/syntax-needed whitespace doesn't count, but a " " literal does count. So your fully expanded version has 119 chars (3 significant spaces)

Answer (score 1):

### Scala, 97 chars

This one gets n from command line.

Thanks to ΤΖΩΤΖΙΟΥ for the * operator

```
val n=args(0).toInt*2
(1.until(n,2))foreach{i=>println(" "*(n-i)+"* "*i)}
println (" "*(n-1) + "*")
```

Answer (score 1):

### Language: [Pike](http://pike.ida.liu.se/)

101 Relevant characters

```
int main (int c, array a) {
    int n=(int)a[1], i,l;
    for(;i<=n; l = ++i < n ? i : 0)
        write(" " *(n-l) + "*" * (l*2+1) +"\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Rhino Javascript shell](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/shell.html): 117 chars minified

```
t=['*'];
for(i=1;i<arguments[0];++i)
{
  s='*'+t[i-1]+'*';
  for(j in t) 
    t[j]=' '+t[j];
  t[i]=s;
}
t[i]=t[0];print(t.join('\n'));
```

minified:

```
t=['*'];for(i=1;i<arguments[0];++i){s='*'+t[i-1]+'*';for(j in t) t[j]=' '+t[j];t[i]=s;}t[i]=t[0];print(t.join('\n'));
```

results:

```
c:\>java -jar C:\appl\Java\rhino1_7R1\js.jar c:/tmp/Xtree.js 10
         *
        ***
       *****
      *******
     *********
    ***********
   *************
  ***************
 *****************
*******************
         *
```

Answer (score 1):

**Language: FoxPro 2.x for DOS (should work with Clipper too), Char count: 62**

```
para n
for h=1 to n
?spac(n-h)+repl('*',2*h-1)
endf
?spac(n-1)+'*'
```

Answer (score 1):

**Language: Euphoria  147 chars (9 relevant spaces):**

```
include get.e
object
    a = command_line(), 
    t = 42
a = value( a[3] )
a = a[2]
for i = 1 to a do
    puts(1, repeat( 32, a - i ) & t & 10)
    t &= "**"
end for
puts(1, repeat( 32, a - 1 ) & 42 & 10 )
```

With only relevant whitespace:

```
include get.e
object a=command_line(),t=42a=value(a[3])a=a[2]for i=1to a do puts(1,repeat(32,a-i)&t&10)t&="**"end for puts(1,repeat(32,a-1)&42&10)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Excessively long version in J (97 chars)**

```
t=:3 :0
d=:0
k=:''
while.d<y
do.
k=:k,((d{((y-1)+>:i.y))$!.'*'((d{((|.i.y)))$,' ')),LF
d=:d+1
end.k,y$k
)
```

Run it this way:

```
t N
```

where N is tree height.

And Merry Xmas (a bit late).

Comment: I got it in 29 characters: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392788/1088931#1088931

Answer (score 1):

### C# 3.0, 158 bytes

```
int n=int.Parse(a[0]);Console.WriteLine(Enumerable.Range(1,n).Concat(new int[]{1}).Select(x=>new string('*',x*2-1).PadLeft(x+n)).Aggregate((x,y)=>x+"\n"+y));
```

Ungolfed:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] a)
    {
        int n = int.Parse(a[0]);
        Console.WriteLine(Enumerable.Range(1, n).Concat(new int[] { 1 })
            .Select(x => new string('*', x * 2 - 1).PadLeft(x + n))
            .Aggregate((x, y) => x + "\n" + y));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### VBScript, 106 characters

```
n = WScript.Arguments(0)
For i = 1 To n
  WScript.Echo Space(n-i+1) & String(2*i-1, "*")
Next
WScript.Echo Space(n) & "*"
```

Usage and output example:

```
> cscript christmastree.vbs 7 //nologo
       *
      ***
     *****
    *******
   *********
  ***********
 *************
       *
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Ruby Newbie (ha! It rhymes!) with his first working solution:

Ruby 164 characters (of readable code)

```
n=gets.to_i-1
(0..n).each do |j|  
    (n-j).times do 
        print " "
    end 
    (1+j*2).times do
        print "*" 
    end
    print "\n"
end
n.times do 
    print " "
end
print "*"
```

Answer (score 1):

## Lua, 113 significant chars

```
s=string.rep;n=tonumber(arg[1]);r=print;for i=0,n do l=s(" ", n-i)..s("*",(n-(n-i))*2+1);r(l)end r(s(" ",n).."*")
```

Comment: The two `n`s in `s("*",(n-(n-i))*2+1)` can be canceled out, yielding `s("*",i*2+1)`.

Answer (score 1):

## Golfscript - 27 chars

```
~:i,0+{.i\-(' '*\.)+'*'*n}%

~:i  # eval the command line arg, store in i  
,0+  # create a list [0..i-1] add 0 to the end  
{}%  # map this block over the list  
.    # make a copy of the list element 
i\-  # subtract the list element from i 
(    # decrease by one more  
' '* # multiply the result by ' '
\    # swap, so the list element is back on top of stack
.)+  # duplicate, add one, add the two numbers together
'*'* # multiply the result by '*'
n    # put a newline here
```

Comment: nice, i did mine before seeing yours, was about to refactor it to look like this

Answer (score 1):

## C++, 188 bytes

```
#include<iostream>    
using namespace std;
#define s string
int main(int a,char**c){int h=atoi(c[1]);for(int i=0;i<h;i++){cout<<s(h-i,' ')<<s(i*2+1,'*')<<endl;}cout<<s(h,' ')<<'*'<<endl;}
```

Ungolfed:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int a,char**c)
{
    int h = atoi(c[1]);
    for(int i=0; i<h; i++)
    {
        cout << string(h-i, ' ') << string(i*2+1, '*') << endl;
    }
    cout << string(h, ' ') << '*' << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Q, 54

```
{-1(-:)[((x+(!)x),x)]$(((&)((!)(2*x))mod 2),1)#\:"*";}
```

example:

```
q){-1(-:)[((x+(!)x),x)]$(((&)((!)(2*x))mod 2),1)#\:"*";} 10
         *
        ***
       *****
      *******
     *********
    ***********
   *************
  ***************
 *****************
*******************
         *
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my first experience with code golf. So advices are welcome :)

**C: 170 chars**:

```
int main(){
    int n,m=1,x;
    scanf("%d",&n);x=2*n-1;
    for(;m<x*n+n+2;m++)
        printf("%c",m==x*n|m==x*n+n+1?42:m==x*n+1?10:m>x*n?32:!(m%(2*n-1))?10:!(m%x<n-m/x)&m%x<m/x+n+1?42:32);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not see a solution using `R`.  The code below may not be efficient, but it seems to work (170 characters with spaces if all code placed on one line):

```
for(i in 1:4){ cat( paste( paste(rep(' ', (3-(i-1))), collapse=''), 
                           paste(rep('*', (2*i-1)),   collapse=''), collapse=''),  
               sep='\n'); if(i==4) cat('    *    ', sep='\n')}


    *
   ***
  *****
 *******
    *
```

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript, 89

```
i=4
c=t=""
while(i){o=c,j=(i--+1)*2-3
while(j--)o+="*"
t=o+"\n"+t
c+=" "}console.log(t+o)
```

## Javascript 81

```
o=s=''
for(a=3;a--;){l=s+=' '
for(k=a*2+1;k--;)l+='*'
o=l+'\n'+o}console.log(o+l)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish): 136 chars

This one's not going to win, but because Christmas is coming again, I thought fish needed a Christmas tree too! (pun intended)

```
1-:&1$>:> :1(?!v~$:> :1(?!vv
        ^-1o" "<   ^-1o"*"<>~2+$1-:0(?!v~~&ao>" "o1-v
      ^                              oa<;o"*"^!?(1: <
```

It can be run as follows with the standard interpreter:

```
./fish.py christmas.fish -v 5
```

... for N=5. (If the file is called `christmas.fish` :P) In this way, one prepopulates the stack with the value `5`. This is the closest I could get to a command-line argument.

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 73 chars

```
val n=args(0).toInt
(1 to n):+1 foreach(i=>println(" "*(n-i)+"*"*(2*i-1)))
```

run as

```
golf.scala 10
```

Comment: Wait, does that display the trunk?

Comment: yes, :+1 would do that

Answer (score 1):

## Dart, 174 characters

```
main(p){var x=-1,r='',a=int.parse(p[0]),b=a,f=(x,y,[z='']){var s='';while(x-->0)s+=y;return s+z;};while(a-->0){x+=2;r+=f(a,' ')+f(x,'*','\n');}print('$r${f(b-1,' ','*')}');}
```

Answer (score 1):

## R, 94 chars

Christmas is over, but anyway:

```
t=function(N){
  f=function(i)cat(rep(" ",N-i),rep("*",2*i-3),"\n",sep="")
  lapply(2:N,FUN=f);f(2)
}
```

For trees of height 2 or more:

```
> t(2)  > t(3)  > t(5)
*        *         *
*       ***       ***
         *       *****
                *******
                   *
```

Comment: We have posted similar R solutions in three minutes ;)

Comment: becomes obsolete, see @djhurio solution

Comment: btw, I have got attracted to this site by the "2014" problem. I have got a 20 chars solution in R, but cannot post it as the question is protected from newbies ;)

Comment: Would be nice to see your 20 char solution for the "2014" ;)

Comment: sum(T+T:exp(T+pi))-T

Comment: Nice one. Should I add it to my answer mentioning you as an author?

Comment: done, see: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/17877/13849

Answer (score 1):

## Japt `-R`, 11 bytes

```
ÇÑÄ î*Ãp* û
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=x9HEIO4qw3AqIPs=&input=OAotUg==)

```
Ç               :Map the range [0,input)
 Ñ              :  Multiply by 2
  Ä             :  Add 1
    î*          :  Repeat * that many times
      Ã         :End map
       p*       :Push a *
          û     :Centre pad each element with spaces to the length of the longest
                :Implicitly join with newlines
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 11 bytes

```
õ_ç* êÃp* û
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn///DW@MPLtRQOrzrcXACkdv//b8zFpRsEAA)

Answer (score 1):

## APL(NARS), 37 chars, 74 bytes

```
{⊃⍵{(' '⍴⍨⍺-⍵),'*'⍴⍨1+⍵×2}¨0,⍨0,⍳⍵-1}
```

test:

```
  h←{⊃⍵{(' '⍴⍨⍺-⍵),'*'⍴⍨1+⍵×2}¨0,⍨0,⍳⍵-1}
  h 5
     *    
    ***   
   *****  
  ******* 
 *********
     *    
  h 1
 *
 *
  h 2
  * 
 ***
  * 
  h 3
   *  
  *** 
 *****
   *
```

Ot: It seems that your sys for know if i'am a human not work good in this chellphone (so I write this because possible this step is not taken)

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), <del>100</del> 99 bytes

```lua
p,r,n=io.write,('').rep,arg[1]for i=0,n do p(r(' ',n-i+1),r('*',i*2+1),'\n')end p(r(' ',n+1),'*\n')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcoxCoAwDEDRq3RLW6NYwdGTqINglYCkJSgeP1oXx//4x7WoZhTkgVJzC50RLYBrJGZcZB/DvCUxNLTIZk0mW7FgALmmKjh8wwOS70rAxOAir//0qS@sqv0D)

Another Lua version, a little shorter.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 79 bytes

```php
while($argn)echo$r[]=str_pad("
",1+$argn--).str_pad("",++$n*2-1,"*");echo$r[0];
```

Run as pipe with `-nR` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/325b1351c48bf4ba05cc7ffa1ddf50e59c9b4e44).

Comment: Save 2 bytes using variable variables: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAkyzMyc1I1VBKL0vM0U5Mz8lVU8myLS4riCxJTNJS4lHQMtcFyurqaenBhJR1tbZU8LSNdQx0lLSVNa7C@asNa6///Tf/lF5Rk5ucV/9d1AwA "PHP – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## Python3,81 bytes

```
n=int(input());
for j in range(n):
 print(' '*(n-j)+'*'*(2*j+1))
print(' '*n+'*')
```

[try it online](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM9ZNBtP//@fZZuaVaGTmFZSWaGhqcqXlFylkKWTmKRQl5qWnauRpWnEpFBSBlKgrqGtp5OlmaWqrawFZRlpZ2oZADQjJPJCEJtf//yYA)

Comment: [79 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM9ZNBtP//@fZZuaVaGTmFZSWaGhqcqXlFylkKWTmKRQl5qWnauRpWhUUgRSoK6hraeTpZmlqq2sBWUZaWdqGQOUIyTyQhCbX//8mAA)

Answer (score 1):

## Zsh, <s>77</s> 64 bytes

Since all these old questions are now open, I think the *oldest* q. on codegolf.se needs a `zsh` answer!

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P@/2FbLOi2/SEFDwzrTRsXQWlOzoCgzryRNQVUlWsVQO1NbO7Y4JiZPQaVYTa1Y21ZLiwsub1isEKP1//9/UwA)

```zsh
s=*;for ((;i<$1;))printf %$[$1+i++]s\\n $s&&s+=**
printf %$1s \*
```

<sub>Hat-tip to [Alastair from Boxing Day 2008](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4274/15940)</sub>

<sub>NB: Putting the **printf** stuff in a [function is no advantage](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/SUOzoCgzryRNQUlVxbA4Jk9JQcWIq9hWyzotv0ghUyEzT6HaUE9PxbDWujpJQSVaxVA7M1ZBpdi6WNtWS8u6lgsqaBirEKP1//9/UwA)...</sub>

<sub>NB2: <s>[original for 77 bytes](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P@/2FbLOi2/SCFTITNPodpQT0/FsNa6uqAoM68kTUFJVSVaxVA7M7Y4Jk9JQaXYuljbVkvLupYLVd4QIh@j9f//f1MA)</s>.. saved 12 bytes by eliminating quotes, braces, trailing newline</sub>

Answer (score 1):

### [Wren](http://wren.io/), 91 bytes

```
Fn.new{|n|
for(i in 0...n)System.print(" "*(n-i)+"*"*(2*i+1))
System.print(" "*n+"*")
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky9KzftfllikkKhg@98tTy8vtby6Jq@GKy2/SCNTITNPwUBPTy9PM7iyuCQ1V6@gKDOvRENJQUlLI083U1NbSQvIMtLK1DbU1OTCUJMHktfkqv2fqJecmJOjYar5HwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), <s>42</s> <s>38</s> <s>32</s> 23 bytes

```
:&1ɧ1⑷:⑻$-⑬*$⑵;`*`*⑸(
'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASoA1f9rZWf//zomMcmnMeKRtzrikbskLeKRrCok4pG1O2AqYCrikbgoCif//zg)

*-9 bytes due to generating odd numbers inside of the map*

### Answer History

#### 32 Bytes

```
¿&1(⑻|:2+)1^⑷:;½ℤ⑻$-⑬*^`*`*⑸(,
,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N////0H41Q41HE3fXWBlpaxrGPZq43cr60N5HLUuAYiq6jyau0YpL0ErQejRxh4YOl87//8YA)

*-6 bytes due to using a mapping approach*

#### 38 Bytes

```
:&®l1(©l|⑬©l*,:`*`*,
,2+©l;®l)&⑬*,`*`,
```

*-4 bytes due to `⑬` operator (space string)*

<sub>Funny story: I *almost* said this was 40 bytes before I realised that I forgot how to count.</sub>

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N///fSu3QuhxDjUMrc2oSFBKAlJaOVYJWgpYOl46RNpBrDZTWVANKaekAhXX@/zcFAA)

I might as well place up the Keg Christmas tree for the year seeing as how it's almost December!

### Explained

```
:&®l    #Store the amount of lines in variable l and the register
1   #Push the number of stars per row
(©l|    #Repeat variable l times
    ⑬©l*,   #Print that amount of spaces
    :`*`*,  #Print that amount of stars

    ,   #Print a literal newline
    2+  #Increment the number of stars
    ©l;®l   #Update the amount of spaces to print
)
&⑬*,`*`,    #Print the bottom row
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 12 bytes

```
Ｇ<Ｎ*‖↑¶Ｍ⊖θ←*
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ASkA1v9jaGFyY29hbP//77ynPO@8ririgJbihpHCtu@8reKKls644oaQKv//NQ)

### explanation

```python
Ｇ<Ｎ*             #Draw a triangle size input N with character "*"
      ‖↑           #Mirror the triangle so it is the right way round
        ¶          #Newline
         Ｍ⊖θ←    #move left input-1 
               *   #"*" character
                   #the result is implicitly printed
```

Comment: Nice answer! I took the liberty of creating a TIO link so others can see it in action, if you'd liked to edit it into your post: https://tio.run/##ASkA1v9jaGFyY29hbP//77ynPO@8ririgJbihpHCtu@8reKKls644oaQKv//NQ

Comment: my bad @Malivil! I meant to add one, but forgot, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 180 chars

```
interface a{static void main(String[]a){for(int N=new Byte(a[0]),i=-1;i++<N;p('*',i%N*2),p('\n',0))p(' ',N-i%N-1);}static<T>void p(T c,int i){System.out.print(c);if(i-->0)p(c,i);}}
```

I believe this is a new record for Java for this question!

```
interface a
{
    static void main(String[]a){
        for(int N=new Byte(a[0]),i=-1;i++<N;p('*',i%N*2),p('\n',0))p(' ',N-i%N-1);
    }
    static<T>void p(T c,int i){
        System.out.print(c);
        if(i-->0)p(c,i);
    }
}
```

This program uses a recursive method to get rid of unnecessary for loops and print calls. Everything in main is run in one for loop.

Comment: The whitespace is there to make it easier to read. The 180 char count is for the necessary characters only.

Comment: Nice. I see that you have already included the reduced version as well.  That would have been what I suggested, and it is generally best to include both versions.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 18 bytes

```
@PPZsXa-_.'*X_M\,a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P/fISAgqjgiUTdeT10rIt43Rifx////xv918wA)

I don't know how pip recognizes this lambda, but it somehow does.

-3 from DLosc.

### Explanation

```
YPPZsXa-_.'*X_M\,ay@0 a → input
              M\,a    map inclusive range of 0 - a, loop var '_'
    sXa-_             repeat space (input - _) times
         .'*X_        repeat * _ times
         .            join them:               
  PZ                  palindromize the result: ' ***' → ' ***** '
YP                    print each item of the array with newline
                      and assign the array to variable y
                  y@0 return first element of y (always a single *)
                      implicitly print it
```

`@y` cannot be used here, since it changes `\,a` in the first statement.

Comment: Nice! Here's [18 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P/fISAgqjgiUTdeT10rIt43Rifx////xv918wA), taking advantage of the fact that `P` returns its operand.

Answer (score 1):

## [MAWP](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MAWP), 45 bytes

```
=M@![![32;1-]`M[42;1-]`M2+=M10;1-]`[32;1-]42;
```

[Try it!](https://8dion8.github.io/MAWP/v2.0?code=%3DM%40!%5B!%5B32%3B1-%5D%60M%5B42%3B1-%5D%60M2%2B%3DM10%3B1-%5D%60%5B32%3B1-%5D42%3B&input=3)

Takes a while for N bigger than 10

Answer (score 1):

## [Rockstar](https://codewithrockstar.com/), 107 bytes

```
listen to N
X's0
while N-X
let X be+1
let Y be N-X
let Z be X*2-1
say " "*Y+"*"*Z

let N be-1
say " "*N+"*"
```

[Try it here](https://codewithrockstar.com/online) (Code will need to be pasted in)

Comment: A good idea would be to append the name of a related rock song to each of your rockstar programs.

Comment: Not a bad idea, @Razetime, I might just do that - I already use song names for [all my challenge titles](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974/shaggy?tab=questions). Of course, if I was anyway skilled at such things, I'd actually write a song in Rockstar related to the challenge!

Answer (score 1):

## [sed 4.2.2](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 62 bytes, `-r` flag

```
s/0\B/ /g
:
H
s/ (0+)/0\10/
//b
:a
s/0(0+)0/ \1/
ta
H
x
y/0/*/
```

Takes input in unary (e.g. `3` is `000`), allowed as per [meta consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5349/58834).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcorDoAwEEVR/1ZRySfkTW0likXUQCAEQwlTAZtnaK88ubqtZkqJIx13BExQukb6tpgXglwQ5oJSUeiiJ/JcvgcvhR3NpPalKx/pVBvuHw)

With comments:

```
#Replace all zeroes except the last by a space
s/0\B/ /g
#Unnamed branch label
:
#Append to hold buffer
H
#Put zeroes around a stretch of zeroes
s/ (0+)/0\10/
#Jump to unnamed label if there are any spaces left
//b
#Create a label a, and recursively remove initial/final zeroes
:a
s/0(0+)0/ \1/
ta
#Append to hold buffer
H
#Exchange hold/pattern buffers
x
#Replace 0s with asterisks
y/0/*/
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby 2.7](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 50 bytes

```ruby
->h{t=(0...h).map{" "*(h-_1)+?**(_1*2+1)};t<<t[0]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6jusRWw0BPTy9DUy83saC6JrNGSUFJSyNDN1NT215LSyNTy0jbULPWusTGpiTaILb2f0FpSTEXiFBIizaO5ULmmqByTWP/AwA)

TIO uses an older version of Ruby, whereas in Ruby 2.7, we've numbered parameters, which saves a byte.

Answer (score 1):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/index), 214 bytes

```clj
(defn p[n](let[c(map #(inc(* % 2))(range n))l(map #(apply str %)(partition 2(interleave(map #(apply str(repeat(/ % 2)" "))(reverse c))(map #(apply str(repeat % "*"))c))))](doseq[a l](println a))(println(first l))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc1BCsJADAXQq4RKIelG7XVKF6FNZSROY2YsePpxKl2Juw95/2fS9f5yKQVnWSLYEEdUycOEDzY4YYgTdtBCT4TO8SYQifQ4spm@IWWHltDYc8hhjdDXVhZX4U1@JbqYcMbzd7OBZt@VTTwJTDX/5xU3XaVVEI04r0meA4OOaF5/aQSu3SPjEjxl0N0WNLheqHwA)

Ungolfed:

```clj
(defn print-xmas-tree-of-height [n]
  (let [asterisk-counts       (map #(inc (* % 2)) (range n))
        asterisk-strings      (map #(apply str (repeat % "*")) asterisk-counts)
        leading-spaces        (map #(apply str (repeat (/ % 2) " ")) (reverse asterisk-counts))
        lines                 (map #(apply str %) (partition 2 (interleave leading-spaces asterisk-strings)))
        ]
    (doseq [aLine  lines]
      (println aLine))
    (println (first lines))))
```

Comment: I think you can make this a lambda instead of a named function

Comment: @Seggan You can't use `#()` because you can't nest them, but you could do `(fn[n](...))`

Answer (score 1):

## Raku, <s>50</s> <s>48</s> 46 bytes

(45 characters, but » is 2 bytes)

```
{(|^$^n,0)».&{printf "%{$n+$_}s
",\*x$_*2+1}}
```

[Try it online!](https://glot.io/snippets/gfzc7j5li6)

Original 50-byte version:

```
-> \n{(|^n,0)».&{printf "%{n+$_}s
",'*'x 2*$_+1}}
```

48-byte version:

```
-> \n{(|^n,0)».&{printf "%{n+$_}s
",\*x$_*2+1}}
```

Comment: `'*'` can be `\*`, instead of `-> \n` you can use a placeholder parameter (`$^n`) and you can rarrange the `2*$_+1` to have `$_` first to save that space

Comment: @jo Thanks! But I don't think I can use a placeholder, because I'm using it inside a nested block.

Comment: You can, just don't add the `^` to the second instance of `$n`, like `{(|^$^n,0)».&{printf "%{$n+$_}s
",\*x$_*2+1}}`

Comment: Oh! Well, then. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

**Language: Erlang, Char count: 151**

A little bit shorter Erlang version:

```
-module(x).
-export([t/1]).
t(N)->[H|_]=T=t(N,1),io:format([T,H]).
t(0,_)->[];t(N,M)->[[d(N,32),d(M,42),10]|t(N-1,M+2)].
d(N,C)->lists:duplicate(N,C).
```

When should run with command line argument

```
-module(x).
-export([t/1]).
t([N])->[H|_]=T=t(list_to_integer(N),1),io:format([T,H]),init:stop().
t(0,_)->[];t(N,M)->[[d(N,32),d(M,42),10]|t(N-1,M+2)].
d(N,C)->lists:duplicate(N,C).
```

Invocation:

```
$ erl -noshell -noinput -run x t 11
           *
          ***
         *****
        *******
       *********
      ***********
     *************
    ***************
   *****************
  *******************
 *********************
           *
```

Answer (score 0):

## GolfScript, 34 characters

Another GolfScript entry:

```
~:x,-1%[x(]+{." "*x@- 2*("*"*n.},;
```

Explanation:

```
~:x                   #read input, store into x
,                     #create array [0,1,2,...,x-1]
-1%                   #reverse it
[x(]+                 #append x-1 to the array
{." "*x@- 2*("*"*n.}, #map each element in array to this block, outputs each line
;                     #remove results of map from stack
```

The block does:

```
{.                    #duplicate value given by map (stack is now: i i)
" "*                  #push " ", times it by i (stack now: i "   ") 
x                     #push x, stack is: (i "   " x), and bring i
@                     #bring i to the front (stack is: "   " x i)
- 2*(                 #pop x,i, push ((x-i)*2-1)
"*"*                  #print that many *'s
n.}                   #print newline, duplicate it so the map doesn't kill it
```

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript, 137 bytes

```
function k(a){var b="";for(i=0;i<a;i++){for(j=0;j<a*2;j++)b+=j>a-2-i
&&j<a+i?"*":" ";b+="\n"}for(i=0;i<a*2;i++)b+=i==a-1?"*":" ";return b}
```

Test case (formatting disorder is due to the first `"` marking a string):

```
k(3)

"  *   
 ***  
***** 
  *   "
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, <strike>119</strike> 116

This one generates the tree on one line:

```
import sys
h=int(sys.argv[1])
print '\n'.join([" "*(h-i)+"*"*(i*2-1) for i in range(h,0,-1)][::-1]+[" "*(h-1)+"*"])
```

It's too bad you have to import the `sys` module in Python before being able to read `argv`.

Being used from Command Prompt:

```
C:\Users\User4\Desktop>treeprint.py 6
     *
    ***
   *****
  *******
 *********
***********
     *
```

I have a Linux box but it can't connect to the Internet and only has Python 2.4, in case you're wondering why I'm using Windows.

Answer (score 0):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), <s>11</s> 10 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
ƨ*αak} *¹╚
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=JXUwMUE4KiV1MDNCMWFrJTdEJTIwKiVCOSV1MjU1QQ__,inputs=NQ__)

Explanation:

```
     }      implicitly started loop, repeated input times
ƨ*          push "**"
  α         append that to the variable A, here defaulted to an empty string
   a        load the variable A
    k       remove the first characters
       *    push "*"
        ¹   wrap in an array
         ╚  center horizontally
```

Answer (score 0):

## Excel VBA, 72 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes input from range `[A1]` and outputs to the VBE immediate window

```vb
For i=1To[A1]:[B1]=i:?Spc([A1]-i)[Rept("*",2*B1-1)]:Next:?Spc([A1-1])"*"
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 83 bytes

```
f=lambda n:'\n'.join([' '*(n-1-i)+'*'*(i*2+1)for i in range(n)])+'\n'+' '*(n-1)+'*'
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, <s>90</s> 89 bytes

```javascript
f=(l,n=1,s="")=>l+1?s+=f(l-1,n+2,l?`*`.repeat(n).padStart(l+n)+`
`:"*".padStart(n/2+1)):s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcgxDsMgDADAvc9gsmNCRdQpEskj8gFQAlUryyBA/T4dc@N9wy@0s35KnyVfcYzkgLU4q5tTCt3GZPdGLgHPVgstmnc/eVNjiaGDoCnhOnqoHZgEyT/8qiZ1rzwXsohrG2eWljkazm9I8EIcfw)

---

Alternative:

```javascript
f=(l,n=1)=>l+1&&f(l-1,n+2,console.log(l?"*".repeat(n).padStart(l+n):"*".padStart(n/2+1)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PclRCoQgEADQu/QRM6u5GH0FtofoBENpFMMoKl3f2J9@37voprLlM9VB4u5bCw5Yi7PoFla27wPwYLWoUW9RSmRvOB7Av@7TmeyTpwqCJtG@VsoVWAnO/3tFvqOyiNgCTNge)

Comment: There's a `padStart` function in JavaScript?? And who says you never learn anything useful in CodeGolf...

Answer (score 0):

## x86 machine code, <s>42</s> 40 bytes

Same limitation as in previous x86 answer (N < 10) applies. It may be lifted by replacing the first four lines with the following six (+6 bytes):

```
start:
    mov si, 82h
    lodsw
    xchg al, ah
    and ax, 0F0Fh
    aad
```

Assembly source code:

```
start:
    mov si, 82h
    lodsb
    aaa
    xchg ax, cx
    mov dx, 0A2Ah
    mov di, dx
    push cx
_loop:
    push cx
    rep stosb
    xchg ax, dx
    mov cx, bx
    rep stosb
    stosw
    inc bx
    inc bx
    pop cx
    xchg ax, dx
    loop _loop
    pop cx
    rep stosb
    xchg ax, dx
    stosw
    xchg ax, dx
    mov ax, 0924h
    stosb
    int 21h
    ret
```

Answer (score 0):

**[SmileBASIC](http://smilebasic.com/en/about/), 55 Bytes**

Takes input from variable 'N'

```
FOR I=1TO N?" "*(N-I);"*"*(1+(I-1)*2)NEXT?" "*(N-1);"*"
```

I think it may be possible to shorten line 2 or 3 in the breakdown below

```
FOR I=1TO N                                                Iterate values of 'I' from 1 to N (One for each layer of branches)
           ?" "*(N-I)                                      Display spaces to offset asterisks, which begins at N-1 spaces long and end at 0 spaces long
                     ;"*"*(1+(I-1)*2)                      Display Asterisks
                                     NEXT                  End loop
                                         ?" "*(N-1);"*"    Display trunk
```

Answer (score 0):

### SAS, <s>70</s> 87 bytes

87 bytes. With a pop window for `N` input.

```
data;
window _ n;
display _;
do i=1to n;
s=repeat('*',i*2-2);
put@(n-i+1)s;
end;
put@n'*';
run;
```

70 bytes. Imperfect, need to assign to `N` handly.

```
data;
n=9;
do i=1to n;
s=repeat('*',i*2-2);
put@(n-i+1)s;
end;
put@n'*';
run;
```

The result is

```
        *
       ***
      *****
     *******
    *********
   ***********
  *************
 ***************
*****************
        *
```

Comment: Do you have a link to this language? Is there really no way to take input?

Comment: @JoKing It is relatively rarely used. SAS is a language to do statistical analysis.